# Current in a resonant circuit using complex impedance

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance, resonance, inductance

I tried to obtain the current $I(t)$ of the shown resonant circuit using complex impedance.

[image: Resonant circuit]

The inductor and capacitor have impedances $i\omega L$ and $\frac{1}{i\omega C}$ respectively.

Using Kirchhoffs voltage law leads to
$$I\left( i\omega L +\frac{1}{i\omega C}\right) = 0$$

**How do I interpret this equation?**

If $I \neq 0$, it leads to $\omega ^ 2 = \frac{1}{LC}$ which is correct.
But it doesn't give a solution for $I$ except $I=0$.

**What has gone wrong?**

As far as I have understood it, using complex impedances is a shortcut to avoid solving the arising differential equation.

Comment: You need to first define v, for example $v = Vsin\omega t$.

Comment: @user45664 But I do not know $V(t)$. I want to derive $I(t)$ without any prior knowledge of how the system behaves.

Comment: By using complex impedances (with $i\omega$)
you implicitly assume harmonic voltage ($V(t)=V_0 e^{i\omega t}$)
and current ($I(t)=I_0 e^{i\omega t}$).

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Oh so using complex impedances only works for harmonic voltages and currents? (So  one cannot use it for any other types of voltages?) If so, would the only way to get the solution $I(t)=I_0 e^{i\omega t}$ be solving the differential equation $$\frac q C + L \ddot q = 0$$?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. When $\omega = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$ then the total impedance is zero, so a current of arbitrary magnitude could flow without being *impeded*, so to speak, just as a zero resistance loop can sustain a dc current without loss indefinitely. When $\omega \ne \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$ then you must have $I=0$ which just shows that the circuit cannot sustain the current indefinitely unless there is a source (here a voltage source in series with the rest or a current source in parallel) to support it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I get the usual solution that the current varies sinusoidally? Using the diff. eq. approach, i.e. $$\frac q C + L \ddot q = 0$$ gives a sinusoidal solution for $q$ and thus $I$.

Comment: if $q$ is sinusoidal then so is $I=\dot {q}$

Comment: But how do I get that from the complex impedance equation? Or is it impossible, i.e. one cannot find the precise form of $I$?

Comment: that complex equation from the very beginning implies that the current is sinusoid, otherwise you would not even have the concept of impedance. Impedance is the ratio of the complex amplitudes corresponding to the sinusoidal voltage and current.

Comment: So would the only way to get the solution $I(t)=I_0 e^{i\omega t}$ be solving the differential equation? $$\frac q C + L \ddot q = 0$$ (Or are there maybe some other shortcuts?)

Answer (score 1):

> **How do I interpret this equation?**
>
> If $I \neq 0$, it leads to $\omega ^ 2 = \frac{1}{LC}$ which is correct.
>   But it doesn't give a solution for $I$ except $I=0$.
>
> **What has gone wrong?**

Nothing has gone wrong other than you do not have a complete solution to your problem.

$I=0$ is certainly a solution as is the charge $Q=0$ a solution.

$\omega ^ 2 = \frac{1}{LC}$ is also a solution but it tells you nothing about the current other than it is not zero and has a frequency $\omega$.

To simplify matters suppose that we consider the charge, $Q$, stored on the capacitor. then applying Kirchhoff's voltage law to the circuit gives $L\dfrac{dI}{dt} + \dfrac Q C=0\Rightarrow LC\ddot Q + Q =0$ which has many solutions, eg $Q=Q_{\rm initial} e^{-i \omega t}$ or $Q=Q_{\rm initial} \cos(\omega t)$ or etc

Putting one of these solution into the differential equation gives $(-\omega ^2 LC + 1)Q_{\rm initial} e^{-i \omega t}=0 \Rightarrow (-\omega ^2 LC + 1)Q =0$ which is of the same form as your equation for current.

So when you use the complex impedances for the inductor and the capacitor you have in a sense already assumed a solution to the differential equation, it will be sinusoidal, and are then finding the natural frequency of the system.